Fragment with Jetpack Navigation takes a long time to load
I made an application with a single activity, in it bottomNavView and fragmentContainerView, here is my activity code:
class AppActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAppBinding
    lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
    private var currentPage = 1

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        binding = ActivityAppBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, 0, systemBars.right, 0)
            insets
        }

        binding.searchBar.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu)
        binding.searchView.inflateMenu(R.menu.search_menu)
        val onBackPressedCallback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(false) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                binding.searchView.hide()
            }
        }
        this.onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, onBackPressedCallback)
        binding.searchView.addTransitionListener { _, _, newState ->
            onBackPressedCallback.isEnabled = newState == SearchView.TransitionState.SHOWN
        }

        makeNavigation()
        makeViewModel()
    }

    private fun makeNavigation() {
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            if (destination.id == R.id.home_nav)
                binding.addFAB.visibility = View.GONE
            else
                binding.addFAB.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            when(destination.id) {
                R.id.home_nav -> currentPage = 1
                R.id.notes_nav -> currentPage = 2
                R.id.tasks_nav -> currentPage = 3
                R.id.habits_nav -> currentPage = 4
            }
        }
    }

    private fun makeViewModel() {
        val noteRepository = NoteRepository(LifeDataBase(this))
        val noteVMProviderFactory = NoteViewModelProviderFactory(application, noteRepository)
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this, noteVMProviderFactory
        )[NoteViewModel::class.java]
    }
}

In all fragments except the first one there should be recylerviews that display data from room db using viewmodel, I have done this so far only for the second fragment
package com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.fragments
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager
import com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.AppActivity
import com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.adapters.NoteAdapter
import com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.databinding.FragmentNotesBinding
import com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.utils.NoteClick
import com.justdeax.lifeorganizer.viewmodels.NoteViewModel

class NotesFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
    private lateinit var noteAdapter: NoteAdapter
    private var _binding: FragmentNotesBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private var query: String? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentNotesBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        
        noteViewModel = (activity as AppActivity).noteViewModel
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreateView: true")

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupRecyclerView()
        updateViewModel()
    }

    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        noteAdapter = NoteAdapter(object : NoteClick {
            override fun onClick(noteId: Long) {
                val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), AppActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("noteId", noteId)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
        binding.recyclerview.apply {
            layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            adapter = noteAdapter
        }
    }

    private fun updateViewModel() {
        activity.let {
            noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { notes ->
                noteAdapter.differ.submitList(notes)
                if (notes.isNotEmpty()) {
                    binding.cardView.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.recyclerview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    binding.cardView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.recyclerview.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

It is this fragment that loads and bottomNav stalls when navigating in this fragment. Here is the graph:
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/nav_graph" app:startDestination="@id/home_nav">
<include app:graph="@navigation/home_nav"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/notes_nav"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/tasks_nav"/>
<include app:graph="@navigation/habits_nav"/>
</navigation>


In each inner graph, only one fragment for each button in bottomNavView
I expect that the fragment will appear instantly without delay as in all normal applications, as in YouTube, in music players, etc.

For a modern implementation don't use fragments, use ComponentActivity and compose navigation: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/navigation
